# Save push notification message into Array IOS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am using Parse.com to send out the push notification message, it is working great, but i want to save those messages into an Array and display for the users in my APP. I have created an NSObject class and declared an array of data to be used throughout the application by other classes. However, when I call the method from AppDelegate class, it returns the address of the notification messages. Am I going right about it?

If someone can help I will be eternally grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, create an NSObject class , and reclare an array, and insert into array.

Comment: i know the workflow, i want to know the detail how to get those message.

Comment: do you mean from where we got pushnotification message?

Comment: yes. i want some example code

Comment: This question is not  cleared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its possible but only in case if user will open application from received push. Otherwise application will not get data from Push notification payload.

### Update:

The answer posted by @Vineesh is correct. To grab the messages out of the push notification that you receive, you need to implement the didReceiveRemoteNotification method as below

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    NSLog(@"userInfo  %@",userInfo);


   // you can get the required message as below

     NSString *msg = [[[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"] valueForKey:@"body"];

}
```

Comment: Yes, when i click the message it will load my Apps. I want to grab the message and save in to Array. any example how to get the message from the push notification ?

Comment: u know what i am asking, thx it works

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines of code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    NSLog(@"userInfo  %@",userInfo);
}
```

In the " userInfo" you can get pushnotification message.